# Special summon 2 Interplanetarypurplythorny Dragon

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Interplanetarypurplythorny Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Interplanetarypurplythorny_Dragon):

> If a monster you control is destroyed by battle or card effect and sent to the Graveyard: You can Special Summon this card from your hand.

Opponent destroyed 1 monster I controlled on field, and I have 2 cards of [Interplanetarypurplythorny Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Interplanetarypurplythorny_Dragon) in hand, can I special summon both of them at once?

Comment: I think this was already asked before... let me check out :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special summoning two Interplanetarypurplythorny Dragons consecutively](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45412/monster-effect-and-special-summoning)

Comment: Yep it was, good question though :) happened that the other post had an incorrect answer. Good thing we sorted this question out

Comment: @DarkCygnus So it really depends on the text of the effect. I was also wondering about [Battle Fader](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_Fader)'s effect, if 2 of him in hand then can I special summon both of them at once? But the text says "When.." so the answer is clearly "No" for the 2nd one because of missing timing.

Comment: Precisely :) you got it now